# How to fix Kingston DT2000 corrupted firmware using Phison MPALL software?

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, firmware

I've just bought an encrypted kingston flash drive but it have some issues. I followed the [guide](https://www.kingston.com/us/usb-flash-drives/datatraveler-2000-encrypted-usb-flash-drive) to set a password,need to press two times the key button...However,when I do this it not works(the blue light doesn't blinks then I'm not able to set my own pass).So I'm trying to find a way to fix the Phison **PS2251-13** firmware running a software called Phison MPALL.I've found some guides on youtube,websites...But anyone had the same controller. So I think I would select different firmware and burner files,but I have no idea how MPALL software works fixing the issue.Would you help me to do it properly,please?

[image]

[image]

**PS:** I downloaded the software in a [russian website](https://www.usbdev.ru/files/phison/mpall/) on **`5.03.0B-DL20`** version. There are three possible burners ***BN07V500T9 / BN07V600T9W / BN07V601TAW*** and just one firmware ***FW07V50353TW***. There are three options of software to use and I choose:**`MPALL_F1_7F00_DL20_v503_0B_fix`**.My current OS is Windows 10 Home.

***EDITED:***

**Attention!** Sorry! I was doing it wrong! Didn't know that to set a password the flash drive need to be disconnected from USB port. It works! I can set my own password now! The firmware is working well! Would I leave my question here even so? What do you think? Thanks!